# Java SPARK saveAsTextFile NULL

Tags: java, apache-spark

```
   JavaRDD<Text> tx= counts2.map(new Function<Object, Text>() {
        @Override
        public Text call(Object o) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (o.getClass() == Dict.class) {
                Dict rkd = (Dict) o;
                return  new Text(rkd.getId());
            } else {
                return null ;
            }
        }

    });
   tx.saveAsTextFile("/rowkey/Rowkey_new");
```

I am new to Spark, I want to save this file, but I got the **Null exception**. I don't want to use **return** **new Text()** to replace **return null**,because it will insert a blank line to my file. So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting an if condition in your map, you simply use that if condition to build a [RDD filter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#filter(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)). The [Spark Quick Start](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) is a good place to start. There is also a nice overview of other [transformations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) and [actions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions).

Basically your code can look as follows (if you are using Java 8):

```
counts2
  .filter((o)->o instanceof Dict)
  .map(o->new Text(((Dict)o).getId()))
  .saveAsTextFile("/rowkey/Rowkey_new");
```

You had the intention to map one incoming record to either zero or one outgoing record. This cannot be done with a `map`. However, `filter` maps to zero or one records with incoming record matches outgoing record, and `flatMap` gives you some more flexibility by allowing to map to zero or more outgoing records of any type.

It is strange, but not inconceivable, you create non-`Dict` objects that are going to be filters out further downstream anyhow. Possibly you can consider to push your `filter` even further upstream to make sure you only create `Dict` instances. Without knowing the rest of your code, this is only a assumption of course, and is not part of your original question anyhow.

Comment: Thanks For your help, It solve my problem. The Spark Quick Start  is really a good place!